# Sum of any k-consecutive terms

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Natural numbers from $1$ to $N=56$ are arranged around a circle in such a way that the sum of any consecutive sequence of $r=5$ numbers is at least $K$. The question is, what is the maximum value of $K$?

(This problem is from the Turkish Mathematical Olympiad in 1995.)

Is there a generalization of this problem? Is it a well-known problem in mathematics?

Using some basic inequalities, we can establish that K is upper-bounded by $\lfloor 5(N+1)/2 \rfloor$.

I wrote a computer program under the assumption that $K = \lfloor 5(N+1)/2 \rfloor$, and it turns out that this assumption holds true only for $N = 10$ when $N<20$.

Edit:

$
\begin{array}{c|c|}
N & K_{\max} & \left \lfloor \frac {5(N+1)}{2} \right \rfloor & \left \lfloor \frac {5(N)}{2} \right \rfloor \\
\hline 6 & 15 & 17 & 15 \\
\hline 7 & 19 & 20 & - \\
\hline 8 & 21 & 22 & - \\
\hline 9 & 23 & 25 & - \\
\hline 10 & 27 & 27 & - \\
\hline 11 & 27 & 30 & 27 \\
\hline 12 & 31 & 32 & - \\
\hline 13 & 33 & 35 & - \\
\hline 14 & 35 & 37 & - \\
\hline 15 & 39 & 40 & - \\
\hline 16 & 40 & 42 & 40 \\
\hline 17 & 43 & 45 & - \\
\hline 18 & 46 & 47 & - \\
\end{array}$

Comment: What is the sequence of values for $K_{max}(N)$ for $6≤N≤20$?

Comment: for N=6 to 18: sequence of $K_{\max}$ will be 15, 19, 21, 23, 27, 27, 31, 33, 35, 39, 40, 43, 46
while the sequence of $\lfloor 5(N+1)/2 \rfloor$ is 17, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30, 32, 35, 37, 40, 42, 45, 47

Comment: The version of 1 to $N=10$ with sum of $ r = 3$ consecutive numbers is a well-known problem.

Comment: For $N = rb + 1$, the better PHP argument is to ignore when $a_i = N$, and look at the $b$ sums of $r$ terms. This tells us that there is a sequence with sum at least $rN/2$.